# TabActivity,Activities containing fragments

Tags: android

I have 5 tabs.Each tab contain multiple activities and each activity contain multiple fragments.

For eg:Navigation needed is  In tab1 - Activity1 - Fragment1_Activity1 - Fragment2_Activity1 - Activity2 - Fragmnet1_Activity2

I used ActivityGroup to show Activity2 inside the Tabs.

ActivityGroupClass:

```
public class CouponsActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {
    private Stack<String> stack;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (stack == null) stack = new Stack<String>();
        //start default activity
        push("FirstStackActivity", new Intent(this, CouponsContianer.class));
      }

      @Override
      public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
        pop();
      }

      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
        pop();
      }


      public void push(String id, Intent intent) {
        Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        if (window != null) {
          stack.push(id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView());
        }
      }

      public void pop() {
        if (stack.size() == 1) finish();
        LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
        manager.destroyActivity(stack.pop(), true);
        if (stack.size() > 0) {
          Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(stack.peek()).getIntent();
          Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(stack.peek(), lastIntent);
          setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
        }
      }
    }
```

From Fragment2_Activity1 am calling Activity2 using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getParent(), RelatedItemListActivity .class);
CouponsActivityGroup activityStack = (CouponsActivityGroup) getParent();
activityStack.push("SecondStackActivity", intent);
```

Issue am facing now is

1. I want to set a transition animation for Activity2
2. On pressing back from Activity2 - last Fragment state in Activity1(Fragment2_Activity1) need to be maintained.

   How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are some kind of replacement of old ActivityGroups and shouldn't be used together. Try to implement your application using only one activity and as many fragments as you need.

Answering your questions:

1. FragmentManager helps you to set an animation. See FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations .
2. Use addToBackStack method to support back button proper way.

Comment: The reason why I am using Activity2 is -I want a slide up animation of a screen that sliding over the bottom screen and this screen should overlap the navigationbar of the bottom screen.For other screens navigation bar is fixed.So the navigationbar is inside the Activity1 layout.If I use a fragment instead of Activity2 it will not slide over the navigationbar